# Testing SignalR App in IIS Express

Tags: asp.net-mvc, signalr, iis-express

Hello everyone I am using visual Studio 2012 and Developed a simple application for vetting purposes only

However I am stuck because when I try to preview the application, I get the Following Error Message

```
[PlatformNotSupportedException: This operation requires IIS integrated pipeline mode.]
   System.Web.HttpResponse.get_Headers() +9681446
   System.Web.HttpResponseWrapper.get_Headers() +9
   Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.OwinCallContext.CreateEnvironment() +309
   Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.IntegratedPipelineContext.GetInitialEnvironment(HttpApplication application) +246
   Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.IntegratedPipelineContext.PrepareInitialContext(HttpApplication application) +15
   Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.IntegratedPipelineContextStage.BeginEvent(Object sender, EventArgs e, AsyncCallback cb, Object extradata) +288
   System.Web.AsyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +285
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155
```

Any ideas on what can be done to resolve this

Comment: Make sure you're using IIS Express and not the development server.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Select your web application project, below Solution Explorer there is a Properties window. Select Development Server > ManagedPipelineMode > Integrated

Comment: I am using Visual Studio 2012. i dont see this option

Comment: Not available in VS 2012. So you can change the server used by right clicking on the project, select properties, hit the web tab, and under the servers section select "Use Local IIS Web server".

Comment: In VS 2012 website (not application), I could right click my project and "Use Local IIS Web Server" directly.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find that option Visual Studio 2012 (Ultimate) either. Changing the Server to IIS Express on *Project Properties->Web* tab worked for me though.

Edit: Apparently that option becomes available when switching to IIS Express.

Answer (score 0):

If everything else fails, see if your project has a vwd.webinfo file that sets useClassicPipelineMode.
I never looked at this file before.  I did just for fun a few days ago and found the following:

```
<VisualWebDeveloper>
    <iisExpressSettings windowsAuthentication="enabled" anonymousAuthentication="disabled" useClassicPipelineMode="true" sslPort="44300"/>
</VisualWebDeveloper>
```

I changed the "useClassicPipelineMode" value and my headaches went away!

Answer (score 0):

Your Application Pool is in classic mode but your Application need integrated mode to fire.  change it to Integrated Mode:

Open IIS Manager

Application Pool

select pool that your app are run in it

In right panel select Basic Setting

Manage Pipeline Mode change to Integrated