# SignalR in OWIN hosted site?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, signalr, owin, ultidev

I get this error when trying to run my web site in UltiDev (version 2.0.20) or in a CassiniDev4 server.

```
This operation requires IIS integrated pipeline mode.
at System.Web.HttpResponse.get_Headers() 
at Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.CallHeaders.AspNetResponseHeaders..ctor(HttpResponseBase response) 
at Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.OwinCallContext.CreateEnvironment() 
at Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.IntegratedPipelineContext.GetInitialEnvironment(HttpApplication application) 
at Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.IntegratedPipelineContext.PrepareInitialContext(HttpApplication application) 
at Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.IntegratedPipelineContextStage.BeginEvent(Object sender, EventArgs e, AsyncCallback cb, Object extradata) 
at System.Web.HttpApplication.AsyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() 
at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

Here is similar related (unsolved) question: [Testing SignalR App in IIS Express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19786928/testing-signalr-app-in-iis-express).

Is there any way to determine which headers are involved in this problem?

Comment: Are you OK with using IIS Express instead of UltiDev or  
CassiniDev? If so, the question you linked to has your answer. I believe that the Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb package needs to run in IIS's integrated pipeline mode which is not supported by UltiDev or CassiniDev.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With ASP.NET Core, this is no longer an issue as I don't need to use UltiDev or CassiniDev4.